# How to do text effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

If someone can give me a hint about how to do the crazy text effect example on this site:
(main title on hover)

http://capitolcouture.pn/

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i really don't have a clue about how to do it

Comment: if you're using chrome, just turn on the dev tools, and you should be good to go from there.

Comment: @Bobby5193 i have tried and didn't find it...

Comment: Looks like html5 `canvas` and some pretty serious javascript

Comment: it's a canvas inside an iframe, and in the head of the iframe document there is a script called main_desktop.js. in that script file you can find everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can easially debug the website too see all the code. Note that the effect is loaded in a `iFrame` so you should open the `iFrame` to look at the code.

The library that is used for this is the 3D javascript library **[three.js](http://threejs.org/)**.

I'm not really familier with this library but i read you need some basic understanding of WebGL if you want to use this library.

You can probably find some great tutorials on the internet of **three.js**

---

Hopefully i give you a direction to look at. *Note that this is not just a beginners thing to do :)*

Comment: Very nice information. +1

Comment: @nkmol thanks a lot for all the info

Comment: No problem, it's a very interesting concept :)